# Open new adaptive card with an adaptive card nodeJs

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to make use of the adaptive cards in bot framework.
I was wondering if i could call a new adaptive card in the conversation using a button in another adaptive card? So not an inline adaptive card, but a NEW adaptive card in the conversation.

How is this possible, maybe some example code?
I can't seem to find a solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you want a new adaptive card, then use OpenUrl Action and point to a method of your bot showing this new adaptive card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Adaptive Card node sample here, that might be helpful: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards/app.js

The Hotel Search card uses an action of type **Action.Submit** and demonstrates one method of how to respond with an adaptive card when a button is clicked:

```
'actions': [
    {
        'type': 'Action.Submit',
        'title': 'Search',
        'speak': '<s>Search</s>',
        'data': {
            'type': 'hotelSearch'
        }
    }
]
```

With code to respond here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards/app.js#L177

And the response:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards/hotels-search.js